# ASP.NET MVC: How can I put the StartDate of a current record on the EndDate of an earlier record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class that makes appointments, the person making a appointments only inserts the start date and time, but the end date must be equal to the start date of the next appointments. My difficulty is in ensuring that the previous appointments always receives the EndDate as the StartDate  of the current appointments

```
public  class InfoAppointments : Entity
{         
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Excluded { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Observation{ get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }  
}
```

EDIT

My Repository:

```
public class InfoAppointmentsRepository : Repository<InfoAppointments>, IAppointmentsRepository
{
    public InfoAppointmentsRepository(RveContext rveContext) : base(rveContext)
    {
    }

    public InfoAppointments FindByName(string name)
    {
        return Search(c => c.Name== name).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public InfoAppointments FindByStatus()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Remove(Guid id)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem then?.

Comment: when I make a appointment, the StartDate  of this appointment must also be saved on the EndDate  of the last appointments. Thats my problem =/

Comment: FYI There is nothing in this question related to MVC or Visual Studio, so I removed those tags. It could be related to e.g. Entity Framework or SQL Server (or some other DBMS), if you now realize that those apply then please [edit] and clarify the question occordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to this, and it may depend on your preference for adding this sort of business logic in your application code or in SQL (e.g. as a trigger). I would personally recommend the former, as this requirement may evolve over time, and may affect other components of your business logic.

I've made a few assumptions: 1) That you are using Entity Framework, and 2) Appointments don't overlap, and EndDate is unique. If that is the case, you could implement this functionality using similar logic to the following:

```
public class AppointmentService
{
    private readonly MyContext _db;

    public AppointmentService(MyContext db) => _db = db;

    public void AddAppointment(InfoAppointments appointment)
    {
        // Update the previous appointment's end date
        var previousAppointment = _db.Appointments
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.EndDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (previousAppointment != null)
        {
            previousAppointment.EndDate = appointment.StartDate;
        }

        // Add the new appointment
        _db.Appointments.Add(appointment);

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

One other comment: based on your explanation, it appears that EndDate should default to null, but you've used a non-nullable type. I would change it to the following:

```
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi!, Yes im using Entity with repository pattern, forgot that information. Yes, the date should be nullable, thks for the advice. I have specific repository for each class and the generic, this is a logic that I should put in the specific then. Using a little DDD pattern can help at these hours hehe